# Process of Elimination (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a system $A x = b$ with $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1 & 2\\ a & a & 3 \\ a & a & a\end{bmatrix}.$$
For which three values of $a$ will elimination fail?

Any hints?

Comment: I can't use a calculator, I must do it by hand.

Comment: So, I found the determinant, where a = 0, a = 3, and a = 1. Is that right? a^3 - 4a^2 - 3a

Comment: Can I do RREF by hand? I'm pretty sure my homework requires minimal calculator work, and I only know how to do RREF in MAtLab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46488/discussion-between-gabby-quattrone-and-moo).

Comment: Type here then?

Comment: I don't know how to do RREF by hand.

Comment: But I don't have what it is equal to. What do I do with a = 0, etc?

Comment: I don't understand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we have $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1 & 2\\ a & a & 3 \\ a & a & a\end{bmatrix},$$ we may take the determinant of $A$ and set it equal to $0$ to give us $$\begin{align}\det(A) &= \begin{vmatrix}a & 1 & 2\\ a & a & 3 \\ a & a & a\end{vmatrix} \\&= a \begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & a & 3 \\ 1 & a & a\end{vmatrix} \\&= a\left(\begin{vmatrix}a & 3\\a & a\end{vmatrix} - \begin{vmatrix}1 & 3\\1 & a\end{vmatrix} + 2\begin{vmatrix}a & a \\ a & a\end{vmatrix}\right) \\&= a(a^2-3a - (a - 3) + 0) \\&= a(a^2-4a+3) \\&= a(a - 3)(a-1) = 0\\ &\implies a = 0, 3, 1.\end{align}$$

Comment: So when a = 0, 1, or 3, that is correct? The elimination will fail. I am checking, I posted an earlier comment